# Integrar linguagem Python a sites. Como?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá , :-) Sou aprendiz em Python, e, tenho a seguinte dúvida:

Como posso começar integrar a linguagem Python à sites? se é possível, quais procedimentos devo seguir?

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito ampla. Qual exatamente é o seu objetivo? Se pudesse dar um exemplo do que você quer fazer, ficaria melhor.

Comment: front-end ou back-end? Quer criar um site escrito em Python ou quer usar Python dentro de um site existente?

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de utilizar o Python para **criar** sites (se é isso que você deseja, pelo que entendi da sua pergunta) é utilizando Frameworks ou micro-Frameworks da linguagem.

Um Framework é um conjunto de bibliotecas que agregam funcionalidades específicas a linguagem. Como assim ? O Python é uma excelente linguagem de programação amplamente usada para criar programas usando orientação a objetos e Data Science, mas ela também pode ser utilizada com outras finalidades.

É isso que os Framwork web fazem. 'Simplificam' toda a complexidade de lidar com protocolos HTTP e banco de dados e permitem que você crie a estrutura que vai rodar por traz (back-end) do seu site. 
O [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) é um Framework extremamente robusto e completo, permite criar sites de forma rápida e dinâmica, já o [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) é mais compacto e indicado para sites de menor complexidade.